# How to remove facet values from y-axis-values while using reorder_within from the tidytext to order boxplots within every facet?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, stringr, forcats

How can I remove facet values from y-axis-values while using reorder_within from the tidytext to order boxplots within every facet?

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse); library(tidytext)

mpg %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = hwy, y = reorder_within(trans, hwy, class, median))) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~class, scales = "free_y")
```

And these are the facet values I want to remove.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `scale_y_reordered()`:

```
library(tidyverse); library(tidytext)

mpg %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = hwy, y = reorder_within(trans, hwy, class, median))) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_reordered() +
  facet_wrap(~class, scales = "free_y")
```